# 1F2 Hypergeometric and Bessel function

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions, hypergeometric-function

$$ _{1}F_{2}\left(n-\frac{1}{2};n+1,2n+1;-x^{2}\right)=\frac{2^{2n+1}\Gamma^{2}(n+1)}{x^{2n}(2n+1)}\left(\left(xJ^{'}_{n}(x)+\frac{J_{n}(x)}{2}\right)^{2}+\left(x^{2}-n^{2}+\frac{1}{4}\right)J_{n}^{2}(x)\right)$$
I just came to  confront this $ _{1}F_{2}$ hypergeometric series while i was integrating a square of a Bessel Function.My question is there a way to prove the above $ _{1}F_{2}$ hypergeometric series in terms of bessel function. I tried methods like taking the square of a bessel function which inturn can be presented in terms of $ _{1}F_{2}$  hypergeometric series but nothing worked out,I hope if anyone could come up with a technique  or a reference mathematical paper regarding to this question.

Comment: Try re-writing the derivative in terms of functions of other orders (cf. https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.6.i), expand the square and use http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.8.E3 See if you can simplify the result.

Comment: Thanks, for giving me the reference material,  let me see if i can simplify.